# android application does not show in the recent application tab

Tags: android, label, android-recents

When i use the Label attribute in the manifest for an activity, it does not show in the recent application list. Code for activity in manifest file is:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label=""
        >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

when i use `android:label="@string/app_name"` , then it start showing in the  recent tab, but i dont want activity label.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? what is the recent application list?

Comment: those applications which were recently opened or closed and a list is maintained in android for those applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is not visible in *recent apps list* because **label** of your main activity is **empty**.

Change

```
<activity...  android:label="">
```

To

```
<activity... android:label="@string/some_name">
```

**Edit:**

If you **don't want to show label** for your activity then do the following.

You must set `android:label="@string/some_name"` in `<activity>` tag

And then write `getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` in `onCreate()` method of your activity you want to hide label of.

This will let you hide the activity label and will show your app in *recent apps* list as well.

Comment: i know the label="" because i dont want label for this activity.

Comment: @Sandhu if you don't set, your app will not be shown in recent list though post your entire manifest, I want to check <application> tag.

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
       ><activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
   android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label=""
  >
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity></application>

Comment: @Sandhu then's no other issue in manifest, you must give any `label` to your main activity and it will definitely work.

Comment: isn't any other method available to so the same, because i want ActionBar without any title or label

Comment: @Sandhu check my edited answer, it will let you have what you want. Set the `label` in activity but **hide** it from your activity.java

Comment: @Sandhu let me know once you try it

Comment: there is one more problem that scrollView does not scroll when i set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", this feature for the activity.

Comment: @Sandhu try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` instead

Comment: i used that but then Edit Text is hidden under the key board, so then i again changed this attribute to adjustPan, it does not scroll

Comment: @Sandhu have you added scrollview? If not then add

Comment: @Sandhu then I can't say why it doesn't scroll.